# Is there a way of resolving pyautogui pixel error?

Tags: python-3.x

My code is raising this the error below, I tried multiples times and yet couldn't solve it. Can someone please help. It's always a pleasure to any idea should in case someone has.

The error is:

```
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

My code is:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

while True:
    posXY = pyautogui.position()
    print(posXY, pyautogui.pixel(posXY[0], posXY[1]))
    sleep(1)
    if posXY[0] == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was fixed simply by running my code on 3.9 instead of 3.8
It's a bug in version 3.8. You were on the right track, as the problem is indeed in this line of the pixel() function:

```
with __win32_openDC(0) as hdc
```

For more information go to

1: [filed at pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/579)

2: [filed at pillow which led to the solution](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5536)

Comment: I use Python 3.8.6 So does that mean that I have to update my Python version?

Comment: This error exists in version 3.8. You can use version 3.9 or even 3.7 to solve this problem.

Comment: Much thanks @Salio I really appreciate your time and contribution.